# Access parameter %build.counter% inside MSBuild project built by TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msbuild-target

I have an MSBuild/C# project having a target trying to access `%build.counter% parameter supposed to be set by TeamCity.

```
<Target Name="TraceBuildParameters" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Build.Counter=$(build_counter)" />
</Target>
```

I can access it in TeamCity project build settings but none of this work in the script:

```
build.counter // msbuild error
build_counter // null
system_build_counter // null
teamcity_system_build_counter // null
teamcity_build_counter // null
```

Is it possible to access this parameter at all, is it exposed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeamCity will send any `system` parameters to your MSBuild script (not `configuration` parameters).  If you explicitly want the `%build.counter%` value, the easiest approach would be to set a `system` parameter as follows:

`system.BuildCounter = %build.counter%`

Then you should be able to reference it as `$(BuildCounter)`.

Alternatively, the `build.number` is already sent to MSBuild as `$(build_number)`.  Depending on whether or not you've customised the build number on the `Configuration -> General Settings` tab, this may save the need for the extra parameter.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks! (I have build.number as x.y.z so want to use it and just 'z' separately)